# How to automatically tag windows server devices from Microsoft Defender or Intune portal?

Tags: azure, security, endpoint, intune, microsoft365

I want to group windows servers with a specific tag and manage them via Defender for Endpoints.
I know there is a custom configuration profile OMA-URI policy to tag windows client devices. Is there any similar policy to target windows server devices ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Defender for Endpoint primarily focuses on protecting endpoints, including Windows client devices. it provides comprehensive security features for Windows 10 and Windows 11 client devices, the server editions are typically managed through other tools like Windows Defender Antivirus and Windows Defender Exploit Guard.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Mohamed Azarudeen Z

You can use OMA-URI settings to tag Windows Server devices in Intune, similar to how you tag Windows client devices and leverage Microsoft Graph API to manage these tagged devices.

Here's the general steps to do this:

1. In Intune, create a Device configuration profile with a custom
   OMA-URI setting. Set the Name, OMA-URI, Data type, and Value that
   you want to use for your Windows Server devices.
2. Assign the profile to your desired group of Windows Server devices.
3. Once the profile is assigned and the devices have synced with
   Intune, you can use Microsoft Graph API to manage these devices
   based on the tag.

You can use the following OMA-URI to tag your devices:

> `./Device/Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/DeviceTag/tagName`

For more information about how to use OMA-URI settings in Intune, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/custom-settings-windows-10